# Retrieving SQL Server Extended Properties From C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

We document our SQL Server database by creating table and column level Description extended properties. We usually enter these via SSMS.

My question is this. I'm creating a C# application where I'd like to read the extended properties for a particular table and its associated columns.

Can someone show me how I might go about doing this?

Thanks - Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [Extract SQL Column Extended Properties From LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486536/extract-sql-column-extended-properties-from-linq-in-c) and see if that's something you could do in your situation.

Answer (score 7):

You simply ask for them using the built-in [`fn_listextendedproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx). The result of this function is an ordinary table result set that you read in C# using your data access tool of choice (SqlCommand/SqlDataReader, linq, datasets etc).

Answer (score 0):

A full example for a simple property:

In SQL Server :

[image]

Code:

```
        String strVersion;
        string cmd = "SELECT value  from sys.extended_properties where name = 'MinimumClientVersion'";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var comm = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            strVersion = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
        }
        Version MinimumVersion = new Version(strVersion);
```